# Cannot create extension property with "jobRole" Postman

Tags: jwt, postman, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to add 'jobRole' as an extension attribute from Postman. After that, I want to map it with user and get that attribute in the token.

I have access token with `Application.ReadWrite` permission. With that token, I tried to call this:

**QUERY**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appID/extensionProperties
```

**BODY**

```
{
    "name": "jobRole",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "User"
    ]
}
```

It is giving error even though I have a resource existing and I'm giving the correct AppId.

**ERROR**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource '2d3c554a-bf16-4b39-80d9-9ff210d6c822' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-07-08T07:19:19",
            "request-id": "c2e96c65-99e3-4387-811b-99282e0b3a8a",
            "client-request-id": "665e60ce-357e-f23d-50f2-4c636bb82bd1"
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with missing piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

**Please note that, you need to pass **`Application Object ID`** instead of Application ID:**

[image]

When I passed the **`Application Object ID`**, I was able create the extension property successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Create extensionProperty - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

Comment: Hi Sridevi, is there any way to get last signed in time and ip address of users in the token?

Comment: Could you please create a new question stating this?

Comment: I posted, can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978033/failed-to-include-signed-in-time-and-ip-address-of-users-in-the-jwt-token