# Failed to include signed in time and ip address of users in the jwt token?

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-graph-api, bearer-token

What approach to follow to include `signed-in time` and `ip address` of users in the jwt token?

Do I need to add extension attributes for them separately like below?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appID/extensionProperties

{
    "name": "ip address",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "User"
    ]
}
```

Or Is there anything that I have to modify in Manifest of my app. I tried all the possible ways that I find but no use:-(

FYI, I used client credentials flow to generate token. I found I can get that from `id token` but I don't how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **note** that using client credentials flow, you cannot get optional claims in the token.

Alternatively, you can make use of either **[Authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)**, **[ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)** or **[Implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)**.

***I tried to reproduce in the same in my environment and got the below results:***

> To include **`signed in time`** and **`ip address`** of users in the jwt token,
> add optional claims like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your app -> Token configuration -> Add optional claims*

[image]

After adding the above claims, I generated the ID token using **`Authorization code flow`** like below:

[image]

**I decoded the ID token via [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/)  and got the claims successfully like below:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response as always, very much appreciated for your efforts.